# Joomla 3.2.3 error when quickstart installing

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, joomla3.0

I make a Joomla Quickstart pack using joomla 3.2.3. But when I am trying to install it I got this error:

`Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_APPLICATION_LOAD"`

But I did the same with joomla 2.5.6 version and it's working great.

Comment: Don't use the Quickstart package. Download Joomla, upload the zip (via FTP), extract it, install it

Answer (score 1):

The error message "**Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error:**" comes when Joomla is unable to connect to the database, Just make sure that your mysql service is running and the credentials in configuration.php file are correct to connect with your installed database.